# Js Variable Reference Quickie

Tags: javascript

Hoping someone can clear this up for me.

Let's say I have 2 globals:
var myarray=[1,3,5,7,9],hold;

and then I do this:

```
function setup()
{
alert (myarray[0]);//shows 1
hold=myarray;
alert (hold);//appears to show 'hold' containing all the values of myarray. first number shown is 1
myarray[0]=2;
alert (hold);//shows the values of myarray with the updated first entry. first numbe shown is 2
}
```

Am I to take it that 'hold' is simply keeping a reference to myarray, rather than actually taking all the values of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I to take it that 'hold' is simply keeping a reference to myarray, rather than actually taking all the values of?

Not quite, both `hold` and `myarray` are references to the same array.

More or less everything in JS is a reference (even `var foo = "bar"` creates a reference to an immutable string).